# Not connecting to database from local website

Tags: c#, sql, iis

I have hosted a website in my local machine IIS. The login page is loading fine, but after I enter the credentials, it is not not redirecting me to the homepage, it just stays on the same login page.

This is the connection string that I am using:

```
    <add name="MyConn" connectionString="server=ajaymeda-pc;database=RoomExpenses;Trusted_Connection=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

P.S: I have lost the source code and only have the compiled version.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the error is anything more than "incorrect password"? Error logs, error displayed on the screen, Fiddler screenshots, etc.?

Comment: Make sure your `RoomExpenses` has login rules for `iis_iusrs` and `NT Authority\Network Service`.

Comment: Check your clients firewall has been configured to allow connection to SQL Server ((the default port is 1433)

Comment: Get a [decompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that the connection information is correct (server and database name). Then make sure that 'Remote Connections' are enabled in SQL.

Also, since it is .Net, you could grab a .Net decompiler (perform a Google search) that will allow you to decompile the DLLs and view the most of the source code. This is probably your last option, but would allow you to at least view what the page is doing and gives you a starting point if you had to redevelop the site.

Answer (score 0):

use this as connection string if this is the issue as you mention:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=RoomExpenses;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**UPDATE #1**

you call this connection string inside your code like below:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ToString()))
{
   try
   {}
   catch
   {}
}
```

Comment: Surely `name="ConnStringDb1"` should be `name="MyConn"` as per the question?

Comment: name can be anything ,you give it the name you want and you will call it by this name inside your code..check update #1

Comment: Indeed but re-read the question: "P.S: I have lost the source code and only have the compiled version." - so he can't change the connection string name.